# Control Attribute with a date Attribute

Tags: product-attribute, date, customer-attribute

OK, this is a little confusing to explain.

What I need is to show an attribute only within a certain time/date frame.

I have a custom attribute which shows text and after a certain date, I want it to disappear.

I am sure it is possible as there is something similar already built into magento which is the special price attribute which works with the special price to date and from date.

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Mike, what have you tried so far? Do you have any code or maybe some info on where you want to show it? It's definitely possible but some more details or a specific technical question would help us with answering this

Comment: I have added the following code to my view.phtml file above short description `<?php echo $_product->getData('customattribute') ?>` which works fine but want it to hide after a date which would be selected at the time the data was entered into the customerattribute field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at calculateSpecialPrice() in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

[image]

```
$dateFrom = $_product->getData('start...');
$dateTo = $_product->getData('end...');

if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval($store, $dateFrom, $dateTo)) {
     echo $_product->getData('customattribute');
}
```

Comment: Hey, I dont mean to sound stupid but I'm not sure how to use this information.

Comment: You need to have create two attributes, start and end date. Then follow the logic from special price.

Comment: if you only want to have the expire date then you could set the start date to  `$dateFrom = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp()`

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you. Really helps not having a start date :)